# Правильно ли подключены фавиконы? Не на всех браузерах работают.

Tags: html

Есть семь сайтов, на каждом из которых подключён фавикон:

- [первый сайт](http://liquidation-ok.ru/);
- [второй сайт](http://bankrotstva-ok.ru/);
- [третий сайт](http://corporate-ok.ru/);
- [четвёртый сайт](http://dolgi-ok.ru/);
- [пятый сайт](http://sudy-ok.ru/);
- [шестой сайт](http://strahovanie-ok.ru/);
- [седьмой сайт](http://registration-ok.ru/).

Фавикон везде подключён одинаково, но почему-то работает не на каждом сайте и не во всех браузерах. Правильно ли прописан код для подключения фавикона?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверил в

```
       IE10 - IE7

       Google Chrome Версия 31.0.1650.63 m

       Mozilla Firefox 26.0

       Opera 12.16

       Safari 5.1.7

корректно работает
```

**Конкретнее ставьте вопрос - какой сайт и в каком браузере фавикон не отображается!
За Вас искать и проверять каждый сайт никто не будет! Эту работу Вы можете и сами сделать!**

Comment: Я вопрос вроде поставил корректно. Который звучал так: "Правильно ли прописан код для подключения фавикона?" Спасибо за отклик. Значит у меня какие-то проблемы.